# Static variables containing all enum options of inner class

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a Location class which extends the Android Location. The idea is that each entity is associated with two main places(Campus A, Campus B), or unknown.

So for example, a shop is located in Campus A, and then has a more specific latitude and longitude. Or a user is at CampusA, and then inside a more specific latitude or longitude.

CampusA and CampusB have their specific latitude and longitude that defines them as well for calculation and map purposes.

```
public class CampusLocation extends Location {

    public enum Campus {
        A(R.string.CampusA, 10, -10),
        B(R.string.CampusB, 30, 8),
        UNKNOWN(R.string.CampusUnknown, null, null);

        public int id;
        public Double latitude;
        public Double longitude;

        Campus(int id, Double latitude, Double longitude) {
            this.id = id;
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }

    private Campus campus;

    public CampusLocation(Campus campus) {
        super("");
        super.setLatitude(campus.latitude);
        super.setLongitude(campus.longitude);
        this.campus = campus;
    }  
}
```

Now, it's also possible to set a specific location, and the code automatically assigns the correct campus. For this I would like to do `CampusA.distanceTo(givenLocation)`. But CampusA is not of type `Location`.

Would it make sense to do the following?

```
private static CampusLocation CAMPUS_A = new CampusLocation(Campus.A);
private static CampusLocation CAMPUS_B = new CampusLocation(Campus.B);
private static CampusLocation UNKNOWN = new CampusLocation(Campus.UNKNOWN);
```

If not, what would a better solution to this be?

Comment: Sorry for a pet peeve of mine, but there are no such things as "static objects". Variables may be static, most certainly, but never objects.

Comment: As for your question, what problem, overall, are you trying to solve? You may need a different approach

Comment: When the app is opened, the location of the user is checked. The app automatically assigns a campus to user (by checking the location and seeing the distance between coordinates) and shows things specific for this campus. The user is allowed to manually change campus. Which means that the user has a campus associated, but also has a location which is independent. Other objects also have a campus associated: shops, buildings, etc.
EDIT: This is all because I think it's wrong to have the campus location defined all over the app. If something changes, a central point of change is better.